# Can `Thread.current.object_id` change inside the thread itself?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm wondering if `Thread.current.object_id` can change *inside the same thread*; that is:

```
Thread.current.object_id #=> 11429860
# some ruby code
Thread.current.object_id #=> 11749360 different from the previous result
```

I guess it doesn't change, but maybe `Thread.current` could be reinitialized by some internal Ruby calls...

I mean, if I run a ruby loop/daemon/long standing script (for example a Rails application) today, I should expect that `Thread.current.object_id` will be the same even 6 months from now?

Comment: This is a good question. I've wondered this myself.

Answer (score 2):

Thread.current can change cause its returning the currently executing thread, the threads object id will not.

Comment: I was not clear, I meant if it can change *inside the same thread*; I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

```
puts Thread.current
#=> #<Thread:0x00000001d87fd8>
Thread.new{puts Thread.current}.join
#=> #<Thread:0x00000001f97120>
```

To your updated question. Yes the thread remains the same as long as it has not been restarted. Computers do not feel the difference between a couple of seconds and six months the way you do.

Comment: I was not clear, I meant if it can change *inside the same thread*; I updated the question

Comment: computer do not, maybe interpreters... ?

Comment: Both computers, interpreters, as well as OS, and whatever else required to run the program.